# Bootstrap responsive utilities - Why not create different versions of the same site?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the bootstrap documentation:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

it suggests for use of

`.visible-xs-*` `.visible-sm-*` `.visible-md-*` `.visible-lg-*` `.hidden-xs` `.hidden-sm` `.hidden-md` `.hidden-lg`

> Try to use these on a limited basis and avoid creating entirely
>   different versions of the same site. Instead, use them to complement
>   each device's presentation.

If I have some section that looks like

```
<div class="visible-xs">
    Mobile view
</div>
<div class="hidden-xs">
    Above mobile view
</div>
```

Then why is that not ok? I imagine if you had lots of them then it might get confusing, but what's the alternative? Imagine that the views are different enough that you can't simply change the content style with media queries.

Comment: Why the down vote and vote to close? It doesn't state why in the bootstrap documentation, and no obvious SO answers relating to this. I am asking what the alternative is to the above if it is discouraged.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, where people downvote you because they can. I upvoted you to counter that. Pretty cowardly just downvoting without explaining a reason for it. Whoever it was. If you don't want to answer it, or you think it's a bad question, just ignore it maybe? because others may not think so.

Comment: Since answers to this question are likely to be opinionated, it's possible it will be closed. Regarding your question - first thought that comes to mind: maintenance. If you're showing/hiding large sections, you're also likely repeating a lot of the same content and controls. Depending on how you manage it, this can become a maintenance nightmare when doing updates. And if you "[create] entirely different versions of the same site" this way, you're basically ignoring the benefits of responsive design - might as well just make a separate mobile site, as was the popular trend before.

Comment: @Serlite So do you think this just applies to site-wide applications? I am using angularjs, and one of my components (the footer) looks very different and has different content. In that case for me, that entire component will have different html/css

Comment: @tic If you can't find a way to resolve the differences between the footer shown on different devices, then your hands are tied. But don't sweat it, as long as you don't make this a habit - based on its wording, the warning primarily relates to over-broad usage of these classes, because at that point you're basically writing a website without responsive design and its associated benefits.